# Null reference exception on empty object initializing

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I have following code. On executing in throws NRE on initializing `model`.

```
var model = new EmployeeModel { };

if (responseUsers.Any(x => x.EmployeeId == model.EmployeeId))
{
    logger.Warn("Issue with employee");
}
```

BUT when I remove or comment that LINQ expression with Any, everything works fine. It looks like completely magic for me and I have no idea why does it work so. Don't know how expression coming after object initialization could affect that initialization. Does someone has any ideas?

p.s. Actually, I have some properties in that `model` object and I populate them on initialization, but is doesn't affect the issue.

Comment: `responseUsers` is null.

Comment: @AntP nope, it is a List

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev: well, then at least one of the items in the list is `null`

Comment: If this is a question about where/how the error is reported, assure us that you did a Clean and a Rebuild etc. Also: Debug/Release/Custom config?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, there is not any nulls. Even there were any, why the exception is thrown in object initialization instead of LINQ query?

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev: because you don't have the current debug symbols, so you see the wrong line. Do what Henk has suggested

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've tried Clean/Rebuild etc. Nothing happened. I run at Debug config